# Name [jdbc/springmvc] is not bound in this Context

Tags: mysql, spring-mvc

```
*org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
Error creating bean with name 'webConfig': 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'getDataSource' defined in com.futor.user.config.WebConfig: 
Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
Failed to instantiate [javax.activation.DataSource]: 
Circular reference involving containing bean 'webConfig' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'getDataSource' threw exception; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: 
Name [jdbc/springmvc] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
    at  org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596)
    at  org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
    at  org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374)
    at  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1395)
    at  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592)
    at  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:849)
    at  org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877)
    at  org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
    at  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:400)
    at  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291)
    at  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
    at  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5155)
    at  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5680)
    at  org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at  org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1018)
    at  org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:994)
    at  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
    at  org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1127)
    at  org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:2021)
    at  java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at  java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at  java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) 
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
    Error creating bean with name 'getDataSource' defined in com.futor.user.config.WebConfig: 
    Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
    Failed to instantiate [javax.activation.DataSource]: Circular reference involving containing bean 'webConfig' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'getDataSource' threw exception; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: 
    Name [jdbc/springmvc] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
    at  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627)
    at  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:456)
    at  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1305)
    at  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1144)
    at  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at  org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277)
    at  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1247)
    at  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1167)
    at  org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593)
```

WebConfig.java:

```java
@Configuration@EnableWebMvc@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
    "com.futor.user"
})

public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate() {
        return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate((javax.sql.DataSource) dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() throws NamingException {
        JndiTemplate jndiTemplate = new JndiTemplate();
        DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) jndiTemplate.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/springmvc");
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry handlerRegistry) {
        handlerRegistry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources");
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/user");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return null;
    }   
}
```

pom.xml:

```xml
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-tx -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>test</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

WebInitiallizer.java:

```java
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class WebInitiallizer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class < ?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new Class[] {
            WebConfig.class
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class < ?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new String[] {
            "/"
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises because autowiring of this bean fail due to jndi lookup failure. Try this:

```
DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) jndiTemplate.lookup("jdbc/springmvc");
```

Comment: Thanks for your concern but I am afraid, that error is still not resolve.